# Virtual Human library for WebGL or Flash

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm looking for a way to load a virtual human (ie; a model rigged with a skeleton, preferably with moving eyebrows/etc) onto a web page. The functionality should be similar to the dated library Haptek Player (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2iIuiT3IW8), but allow for a transparent background. Ideally it would be in WebGL/O3D since it can be directly integrated with my existing code. However, if there's an implementation out there already in Flash3D or a different plugin, I can quickly switch my codebase to actionscript.

I've investigated trying to send the Haptek Player vertices to a Float32Array (used by WebGL) using an npapi plugin. I can place the vertex data into a javascript array and draw the virtual human. The vertex data cannot be changed, however, since the array must be copied to a typed array (Float32Array) to be used by WebGL.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

try http://expression.sourceforge.net/

C++ and OpenGL

Comment: The OP asked for a Javascript solution and you are proposing a server side OpenGL solution??????

Answer (score 0):

you can experiment with converting the code to javascript using emscripten